# Active Admin: Keeping top menu navbar with new custom page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, activeadmin

I have an active admin panel with other models involved including a custom one.  I want to keep the top navbar when redirecting to a new admin page.

Main page:
[image: main page]

custom Page transactions:  " I click on transactions "
[image: custom page]

Transactions admin model: "My custom admin Page"

```rails
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Transactions" do
  # content do
  #   para "Hello World"

  #   render partial: 'transactions'
  #   # render :template => "transactions" 
  #   end
controller do
    def index

       @reservations = Reservation.where("transaction_id = transaction_id", true)
        # @reservations = Reservation.all

    end

    private
  def find_reser
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
  end

  end


end
```

All in all I want to keep the the navbar at the top!! Im sure I add something in my transactions admin model. Which is my custom model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried researching the [ActiveAdmin Documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#customize-the-menu).

You can configure the menu on the activeadmin config file.

Example:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
      menu.add label: 'Admin Users', priority: 1
      menu.add label: 'Boards', priority: 2
      menu.add label: 'Comments', priority: 3
      .
      .
      .
      menu.add label: 'Transactions', priority: 8
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but yes I already have this code. unfortunitly the nav bar works for all except custom view :/